# Lark parser Indenter class not working while using lark.visitors.Interpreter class

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, lark-parser

So I'm making a programming language using the `lark` library in python, up until now, I was using the class `Transformer()`, but now I've switched to the `lark.visitors.Interpreter()` class. I've been copying over my progress from `Transformer` to `Interpreter`, but I cant seem to get the `Indenter` class working. For example, if I parse

```
5 + 5
5 + 5
```

When I parse this, I'm getting the following error:

```py
PS E:\ParserAndLexer> & C:/Python38/python.exe e:/ParserAndLexer/lite/lite_interpreter.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\lark\parsers\lalr_parser.py", line 59, in get_action
    return states[state][token.type]
KeyError: 'NUMBER'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/ParserAndLexer/lite/lite_interpreter.py", line 46, in <module>
    tree = parser.parse(lite_code)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\lark\lark.py", line 464, in parse
    return self.parser.parse(text, start=start)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\lark\parser_frontends.py", line 148, in parse
    return self._parse(token_stream, start, set_parser_state)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\lark\parser_frontends.py", line 63, in _parse
    return self.parser.parse(input, start, *args)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\lark\parsers\lalr_parser.py", line 35, in parse
    return self.parser.parse(*args)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\lark\parsers\lalr_parser.py", line 88, in parse
    action, arg = get_action(token)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\lark\parsers\lalr_parser.py", line 66, in get_action
    raise UnexpectedToken(token, expected, state=state, puppet=puppet)
lark.exceptions.UnexpectedToken: Unexpected token Token('NUMBER', '5') at line 2, column 1.
Expected one of:
        * __ANON_0
        * $END
```

My code looks somewhat like this:

```py
from lark.visitors import Interpreter
from lark import Lark
from lark.indenter import Indenter

class MainIndenter(Indenter):
    NL_type = '_NL'
    OPEN_PAREN_types = ['LPAR', 'LBRACE']
    CLOSE_PAREN_types = ['RPAR', 'RBRACE']
    INDENT_TYPE = '_INDENT'
    DEDENT_type = '_DEDENT'
    tab_len = 8

class MainInterpreter(Interpreter):
    number = int
    string = str
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.vars = {}

    def add(self, tree):
        return int(tree.children[0]) + int(tree.children[1])

    def sub(self, tree):
        return int(tree.children[0]) - int(tree.children[1])

    def mul(self, tree):
        return int(tree.children[0]) & int(tree.children[1])

    def div(self, tree):
        return int(tree.children[0]) / int(tree.children[1])

parser = Lark.open('lite\lite_parser.lark',
                   parser='lalr', postlex=MainIndenter())

grammar = '''
?start: expr

?expr: STRING            -> string
     | NUMBER            -> number
     | NUMBER "+" NUMBER -> add
     | NUMBER "-" NUMBER -> sub
     | NUMBER "*" NUMBER -> mul
     | NUMBER "/" NUMBER -> div
     | STRING "+" STRING -> str_add
     | NAME              -> get_var

%import common.ESCAPED_STRING -> STRING 
%import common.NUMBER
%declare _INDENT _DEDENT
%import common.WS_INLINE
%ignore WS_INLINE
%import common.NEWLINE -> _NL
%ignore _NL
'''
test_input = '''
5 + 5
5 + 5
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = parser.parse(test_input)
    print(MainInterpreter().visit(tree))
```

Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your grammar only allows a single expression. It can parse `5+5` fine, but fails on the second `5 + 5`. You would have to extend your grammar with some kind of recursion to parse multiple expressions. For example, you could add a rule `| expr expr` to `expr`. This would allow you to parse your example input, resulting in `[10,10]`.

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks alot!

Comment: How do I make the result not a list?

Comment: Can you provide an example for what kind of result you want instead of a list? Do you want to combine the results of all expressions in some way?